# enabalajx() not defined

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i m building a web control in aspx 3.5 in which i m using ajax hover menu extender. it works fine in chrome. but in IE8 it crashes when i hover over a button. when i check in chrome error  given there is Uncaught ReferenceError: enabalajax is not defined. please help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Try using `enableajax`

Answer (score 0):

you are definitely spelling `enable` wrong...